# Realm Android how to get deleted item

Tags: android, kotlin, realm, realm-list

I'm looking to synchronise my database with a server.
For this I'd like to know which realm objects have been deleted.

I've been trying to retrieve the deleted objects from the change listener and its `changeSet.deletions`.

As stated in the documentation:

> The deleted indices in the previous version of the collection

Is it possible to get a reference of the previous collection? What are the possible strategies here to retrieve a deleted item?

Comment: How about not deleting an item but giving it a deleted boolean?

Comment: Works on paper but that's really not what I'm looking for :)

Comment: You can do a 'soft delete' what is what @noev was referring to - or - what we do when a user deletes an object, we first create an unmanaged copy of that object and store it in a class variable then perform the delete on the managed object. When the notification fires, you'll know the index of the object that was deleted but that doesn't sound like it's important - you want the object data - which you can then get from that var. Once we do something with that unmanaged object, "User name X was deleted!", for example, then nil it out.